# Postgres streaming replication over Internet

Tags: postgresql, replication, internet

all:

I want to set up two PostgreSQL servers, one as master  server and the other one as a hot standy, using streaming replication. I have done this before in LAN environments, but I would like to know how well it performs over the Internet. Specifically, I would be replicating production from my datacenter to a AWS or similar, using a 20 Mb/s symmetric, shared connection. Has anyone had experience in such deployments? How well has it worked for you? Any special considerations I should keep in mind?

Thanks.

Comment: How much data are you inserting or updating?

Comment: It's not that much, I'd be surprised if it amounted to more than 100 MB throughout the day.

Comment: I see nothing to worry about then. You can push more than that over a dialup connection! (If nobody else is using it...)